# Are all proteins translated by the RER ribosomes destined for the Golgi apparatus?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, translation

The proteins translated by the free ribosomes can fold in the cytoplasm and never go through the endomembrane system. But when the endomembrane system is described, it is always stated that the proteins are transferred from the ER to the Golgi and then to their destination. Are there any known proteins that skip that Golgi step? I've searched for a long time but could not find any information on this.